# Multiple div shown on the add button click how to delete the same div through the delete button

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

```js
var count = 2;
var countMax = 5;

function adddt() {
  if (count > countMax)
    return;
  document.getElementById('dt-' + count + '').style.display = 'block';
  count++;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3" align="right">
  <button class="add-plus-btn btn1" onclick="adddt()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button> </div>

<div class="row" id="dt-1" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-12" style="height: 40px;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <label for=""></label>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 Option">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Max Chars 500" style="width: 700px !important;"></textarea>


      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3" align="right">
        <button class="add-plus-btn btnminus1"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="dt-2" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-12" style="height: 40px;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <label for=""></label>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 Option">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Max Chars 500" style="width: 700px !important;"></textarea>


      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3" align="right">
        <button class="add-plus-btn btnminus1"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="dt-3" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-12" style="height: 40px;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <label for=""></label>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 Option">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Max Chars 500" style="width: 700px !important;"></textarea>


      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3" align="right">
        <button class="add-plus-btn btnminus1"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using the above code to show multiple divs one by one by clicking on the 'add' button. Now I want to hide the same divs when I click on the delete or minus button. Requesting you please guide how can I solve this. I tried using the show hide method but it would not work for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>

<body>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="col-sm-3" align="right">
  <button class="add-plus-btn btn1" onclick="adddt()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>                                                                                                        </div>
                                                          
  <div class="row" id="dt-1" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-12" style="height: 40px;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
    
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
            <label for=""></label>
        </div>
      
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 Option">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Max Chars 500" style="width: 700px !important;"></textarea>
        </div>
          
      <div class="col-sm-3" align="right">
      <button class="add-plus-btn btnminus1" onclick="deletdt(1)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="dt-2" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-12" style="height: 40px;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
      
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
            <label for=""></label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 Option">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Max Chars 500" style="width: 700px !important;"></textarea>
        
        
          </div>
            
        <div class="col-sm-3" align="right">
        <button class="add-plus-btn btnminus1" onclick="deletdt(2)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="dt-3" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-12" style="height: 40px;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
      
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
            <label for=""></label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 Option">
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Max Chars 500" style="width: 700px !important;"></textarea>
        </div>
            
      <div class="col-sm-3" align="right">
      <button class="add-plus-btn btnminus1" onclick="deletdt(3)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

<script>
  var count = 1;
    var countMax = 3;

    function adddt() {
      if(count > countMax)
        return;
      document.getElementById('dt-' + count + '').style.display = 'block';
      count++;
    }

    function deletdt(id)
    {
      document.getElementById('dt-' + id + '').style.display = 'none';
    }

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function delete() {
   if(count > countMax)
      return;
   document.getElementById('dt-' + count + '').style.display = 'none';
   count++;
}
```

if you change value to `"display: none;"` instead of `"display: block;"` it will work.

Comment: this would not work when i put same js another button

Comment: i want add and delete both button on screen and both will work accordingly